# Error when try run angular-fullstack client boilerplate

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm build my first Angular project and i followed the [angular-fullstack](https://angular-fullstack.github.io/get-started) guide.

info:

```
Angular Fullstack v5.0.0-rc.4
Out of the box I create an Angular app with an Express server.

# Client

? What would you like to write scripts with? Babel
? Would you like to use Flow types with Babel? No
? What would you like to write markup with? HTML
? What would you like to write stylesheets with? CSS
? Would you like to include Bootstrap? No

# Server

? What would you like to use for data modeling? (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)Mongoose (MongoDB)
? Would you scaffold out an authentication boilerplate? No
? Would you like to use WebSockets? No

# Project

? What would you like to write tests with? Mocha + Chai + Sinon
? What would you like to write Chai assertions with? Expect
```

The full log is very extensive and can be find [here](https://pastebin.com/3qsZgmSV).

when i start the server with `npm run start:server` its connect to my MongoDB and works perfectly but when starts the client(npm run start:client) the follow error occurs

```
ERROR in ./client/app/main/main.component.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: user_path/pokemon-manager/client/app/main/main.component.js: Unexpected token, expected , (21:30)
  19 |     ngOnInit() {
  20 |         return this.http.get('/api/things')
> 21 |             .subscribe((things: []) => {
     |                               ^
  22 |                 this.awesomeThings = things;
  23 |             });
  24 |     }

 @ ./client/app/main/main.module.js 22:12-39
 @ ./client/app/app.module.js
 @ ./client/app/app.js
Child html-webpack-plugin for "..\client\app.html":
                 Asset      Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    ../client/app.html  28.6 KiB       0
    Entrypoint undefined = ../client/app.html
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

this can be find fully [here](https://pastebin.com/m4QS5cRB)